# How can I pass variable to sendline as argument

Tags: python

I am trying to take input from file and read line by line and pass it to sendline as below. But it says invalid syntax. How can I send variable to sendline ?

```
cmds = open("argv[1]","r")
i = 0
while ( i < 2):
    cmd = cmds.readline()
    telconn.sendline(cmd);
    telconn.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
    show_mpls[i] = telconn.before
    i = i+1
cmds.close()
```

Comment: First fix might be to remove the double quotes around argv[1] -- you're not opening the filename passed as the first argument, you're literally opening a file called "argv[1]" for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you

```
import sys
cmds = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
i = 0
while ( i < 2):
    cmd = cmds.readline()
    telconn.sendline(cmd);
    telconn.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
    show_mpls[i] = telconn.before
    i = i+1
cmds.close()
```